# How can I add MX record for a subdomain using cPanel?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have recently created a subdomain in cPanel.

I want to use that subdomain for office 365 email service. I could not create the MX record for that subdomain in cPanel's  zone editor.  How do I do that?

Comment: You don't say how you are trying to add it.  Are there any errors?  Does your hosting service allow you to add subdomains?  We can't answer this question based on the information you have provided

Comment: @radhapiyari You might have an older version of cPanel. That functionality has only been added to versions > 64 (released March, 2017). See the bottom post in this cPanel forum question: [Add mx records for subdomains in the new interface](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/add-mx-records-for-subdomains-in-the-new-interface.592615/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try to be more specific in my future questions and will include the steps that I actually took and the errors occurred during those steps.@Steve
Thank you.

Comment: @dan Thanks for the link. I checked the version of my cpanel which is >64 .

It still does not allow me to add the MX record for the subdomain I have recently created. 
I have emailed the issue to the hosting company and waiting for their reply.

Answer (score 1):

The MX Record always have to be a string of characters, which resolves to the IP address of the Mail Service where you would like to receive emails.

Usually it can be edited by your HOSTING COMPANY if you wish to use another email provider.

So you must register with office 365 email service, and ask your HOSTING COMPANY to change your MX records to what the office 365 is giving you.

Also, you yourself can change MX records if you have an updated CPANEL from "Zone Editor". But you must be sure what you are doing as they are important for the receiving of your emails.

Here is an example:

CPANEL > Zone Editor > Manage > MX >

Priority: 0

Destination: example.com

Comment: I agree with all your information. 

However , after some research I found that there is some issue with cpanel when it comes to adding a MX record for a SUBDOMAIN.

 https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/add-mx-records-for-subdomains-in-the-new-interface.592615/
I have emailed the issue to the hosting company and am waiting for their reply. Will update as I hear from them.

Comment: One of CPanel staffs is saying: "you should utilize a separate DNS zone (by adding the subdomain as an Addon domain) if you want a subdomain name to have it's own separate MX record (different from the primary domain name)." Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't add the subdomain as "Addon Domain"  as I had already created a subdomain under "subdomain" service. Also , I had successfully added all domain records but MX reccord. The system didn't allow me to add MX records only. According to this link https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/add-mx-records-for-subdomains-in-the-new-interface.592615/ the functionality is added but it is not. I asked the domain manger to add the record and he did it but when i asked him how did he do that there was no reply. Strange.Next time i might try to utilize "addon domain" service in cpanel.
BTW Thank you.